# Из списка сделать цельное число

Tags: python, системы-счисления

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему на Python
Из `[0,1,0,1]`, нужно получить -> `0101`

Что угодно уже делал, проблему это не решило. Необходимо для корректного перевода из *двоичной* системы в *десятичную*

```
ts = ['0','1','0','1']
ts = int(ts)
print(int(ts,2))
```

p.s. На других языках лень

Comment: ну покажите хотя бы Ваши попытки, что пробовали

Comment: подождите секунду

Comment: Если что, `0101` и `101` это одно и то же число

Comment: в основной программе в списке оно всегда записано так, по причине того, что числа генерируются рандомно

Comment: сборка массива в строку делается join `''.join(ts)` а дальше уже со строкой делайте что считаете нужным

Comment: Mike, спасибо за ответ